# Unmarshal dynamic YAML to map of structs

Tags: go, yaml, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal the following YAML (using gopkg.in/yaml.v2):

```
m:
  - unit: km
    formula: magnitude / 1000
    testFixtures:
      - input: 1000
        expected: 1
l:
  - unit: ml
    formula: magnitude * 1000
    testFixtures:
      - input: 1
        expected: 1000
```

With the following code:

```
type ConversionTestFixture struct {
    Input    float64 `yaml:"input"`
    Expected float64 `yaml:"expected"`
}

type conversionGroup struct {
    Unit         string                  `yaml:"unit"`
    Formula      string                  `yaml:"formula"`
    TestFixtures []ConversionTestFixture `yaml:"testFixtures"`
}
conversionGroups := make(map[string]conversionGroup)

err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), &conversionGroups)
if err != nil {
    return
}

fmt.Println("conversionGroups", conversionGroups)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Received unexpected error:

yaml: unmarshal errors:

  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!map into []map[string]main.conversionGroup
```

The top level properties are dynamic so I need to parse them as string, every other key in the structure will always be the same, hence the structs for those parts. How can I parse this?

(full code are at https://github.com/tirithen/unit-conversion/blob/master/convert.go#L84)

Comment: What is "dynamic YAML"? There is no mention of "dynamic" in the [YAML specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html). What "top level" are you referring to? I would assume the mapping at the root of the data structure that YAML represents, but that mapping has no properties, as it doesn't have an anchor, nor a tag. Please **edit** your post to make clear what you refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the contents of your `m` and `l` aren't `conversionGroup`s but lists of `conversionGroup`s.

Try this:

```
conversionGroups := make(map[string][]conversionGroup)
```

and it should parse. Note the `[]` before `conversionGroup`.

Then the question is whether that's the structure you really want :)

Comment: Thanks the missing square brackets was the problem it seem. :) Now it parses, I guess I thought the [string] part was enough.